# How to get the source code for a binary?

Tags: apt, source-code

If I'm unhappy about something a binary does, let's say `/sbin/ip`, how do I find the source code and where to send a patch to?

Answer (score 2):

1. `dpkg -S /sbin/ip` to map from the binary to the package containing it (here, the package is "iproute2")
2. Enable source code repos in sources.list (easiest done via the "Software & Updates" config dialog)
3. `sudo apt update` to actually fetch the list of available sources
4. `apt source iproute2` to dump the source in the current directory.

New-style source packages will have a [.dsc file](https://wiki.debian.org/dsc) which contains helpful information like the maintainer and git (or other VCS) repo location.

Comment: of course, first you should check whether the "missing" feature (here: color output) isn't already present but disabled by default.